# How do I fix 500 Internal Error with Flask/Heroku?

Tags: flask, heroku

I have successfully deployed my Flask/PostgreSQL web app on Heroku. It's supposed to consist of two pages. The second page should open. However, instead I get the error described in the title.

This is my first web app. Where and how do I look for the error? Any help is appreciated, thank you for your patience.

````
    ```from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from send_email import send_email
    from sqlalchemy.sql import func
    
     
    app=Flask(__name__)
    # app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgresql://postgres:***@localhost/height_collector'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgres://noiilxmwxinrrz:3ebb4e8e5f6002a4340466bcfba5272dd491dbafbc04aa3523154c1ffc10936b@ec2-52-86-73-86.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/db1dr24ra03kco?sslmode=require'
    db=SQLAlchemy(app)
     
    class Data(db.Model):
        __tablename__="data"
        id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        email_=db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
        height_=db.Column(db.Integer)
     
        def __init__(self, email_, height_):
            self.email_=email_
            self.height_=height_
     
    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")
      
    @app.route("/success", methods=['POST'])
    def success():
        if request.method=='POST':
            email=request.form["email_name"]
            height=request.form["height_name"]
            if db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.email_==email).count() == 0:
                data=Data(email,height) 
                db.init_app(app)
                db.session.add(data)
                db.session.commit()
                average_height=db.session.query(func.avg(Data.height_)).scalar()
                average_height=round(average_height,1)
                count=db.session.query(Data.height_).count()
                send_email(email,height,average_height,count)
                return render_template("success.html")
        return render_template('index.html',
        text="Seems like we've got something from that email address already!")
     
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.debug=True
        app.run()

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def send_email(email, height,average_height,count):
    from_email="***.com"
    from_password="***"
    to_email=email 

    subject="Height data"
    message="Hey there, your height is <strong>%s</strong> cm. <br> Average height of all is <strong>%s</strong> cm, and that is calculated out of <strong>%s</strong> of people. <br> Thanks! " % (height, average_height, count)

    msg=MIMEText(message, 'html')
    msg['Subject']=subject
    msg['To']=to_email
    msg['From']=from_email

    gmail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    gmail.ehlo()
    gmail.starttls()
    gmail.login(from_email, from_password)
    gmail.send_message(msg) ```
````

[Image of Heroku log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIt3s.jpg)

Comment: "where do I look for my mistake?"—start by checking your logs. Since you're using Heroku, start by running `heroku logs`. ([HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that the GET method is not enabled on the success route.
So change it to:

```
@app.route("/success", methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Another issue is that you haven't installed the `psycopg2` module. You would need to do that in a `requirements.txt` file.

Also you're not rendering a template when the `if db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.email_==email).count() == 0:` statement evaluates to False.

There may be other issues.

Comment: What should I change that line to? I attached heroku logs as well. I'm a newbie so heroku logs is not too helpful, I'm pretty much googling all the errors at the moment.

Comment: Change it to what I have posted. GET needs to be allowed on that route.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to install psycopg2, I installed psycopg2 binary. I listed pyscopg2 in the requirements.txt file though. I hope it works.

Comment: You're welcome. Tell us if it doesn't work, and we'll try to assist further.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so very much!

Comment: You're very welcome. Feel free to accept the answer with the checkmark. Happy coding to you.